# How to calculate the direction of shear stress due to shear force on a circular cross section?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses, solid-mechanics

For a circular cross section, we know that the shear stress due to a shear force at the boundary (the radius of the circle) has to be tangent to the curvature. This is so that we have no radial shear stress. However, I was wondering how could we calculate the direction of the resultant shear stress vectors at any point (x, y). Either as an angle or a normal vector. Is there a formula for this? I tried searching for it but was unable to find it.
[image]

Also, what would the magnitude of the resultant shear vector be? Would it still be the value of the shear stress formula:

[image]

or does this formula only work for the vectors along the vertical axis?

Any help is appreciated.